# Captionless but moveable WinForms form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to create a captionless but one-side moveable WinForms form. Is it possible?

Here is a sample from VB6 application I am porting (I added cursor in Paint :) ):

[image]

Comment: Is your question about how to move the form when you have hidden the title bar? If so, what does "one-sided moveable" mean?

Comment: It means form is moveable only by the upper side (where the cursor is painted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the FormBorderStyle = None and then use mouseover and mouse down events to custom handle your move or look into the SplitContainer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here you go, the below code will make sure that the form can be moved only vertically:

```
public partial class FrmMain : Form {
    Point mouse_offset;

    private void FrmMain_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        mouse_offset = new Point(-e.X, -e.Y);
    }

    private void FrmMain_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
            Point mousePos = Control.MousePosition;
            mousePos.Offset(0, mouse_offset.Y);
            mousePos.X = this.Location.X;
            this.Location = mousePos;
        }
    }
}
```